# Android: Grouped notifications and summary still shown separately on 4.4 and below

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-wear-notification

I want to implement [stacked notifications on Android Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) To do that I create 1 summary notification and N individual notifications for each "item". I want only the summary to be shown on the phone. Here's my code:

```
private void showNotifications() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    showNotification1(notificationManager);
    showNotification2(notificationManager);
    showGroupSummaryNotification(notificationManager);
}

private void showNotification1(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    showSingleNotification(notificationManager, "title 1", "message 1", 1);
}

private void showNotification2(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    showSingleNotification(notificationManager, "title 2", "message 2", 2);
}

protected void showSingleNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager,
                                      String title,
                                      String message,
                                      int notificationId) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setGroupSummary(false)
            .setGroup("group");
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}

private void showGroupSummaryNotification(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Dummy content title")
            .setContentText("Dummy content text")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                    .addLine("Line 1")
                    .addLine("Line 2")
                    .setSummaryText("Inbox summary text")
                    .setBigContentTitle("Big content title"))
            .setNumber(2)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_EVENT)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setGroup("group");
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(123456, notification);
}
```

This works just fine on Android 5.1, only the summary is shown in the phone's notification bar:

[image]

But on Android 4.4 it also shows individual notifications 1 and 2:

[image]

In both cases notifications on Android Wear are shown in a stack, as desired. How do I make Android 4.4 only show the summary notification in the notification bar?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Fixed this by using

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

instead of

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

and replacing NotificationManager with NotificationManagerCompat in corresponding method signatures.

Comment: This works on Android 4.4 but doesn't work on 4.0.4.

Comment: Right on target. Perfect Answer

Answer (score 0):

You Just Remove `showSingleNotification` method and replace

```java
notificationManager.notify(123456, notification);
```

with

```
notificationManager.notify(123456, builder);
```

and its work fine.