# nativescript-background-http file uploading notifications

Tags: nativescript

I upload files to server and get notifications on my android device

[image: upload notification]

What can I do to combine notifications  into a stack?

Comment: which plugin are you using for push notification?

Comment: this might help https://blog.hopbucket.com/merge-firebase-notifications-9f96de7d026a

Comment: I not use any plugin, messages show when upload end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin uses [android-upload-service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/) library which is responsible for publishing notifications. The library assigns a [Group](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/blob/master/uploadservice/src/main/java/net/gotev/uploadservice/UploadTask.java#L494) for each notification so everything is stacked, but if you want to combine them with a summary then you must explicitly create a summary notification with same group so everything will be combined into one.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483772/android-grouped-notifications-and-summary-still-shown-separately-on-4-4-and-bel) may show you how to create a summary notification, you will have to assign the same [group used in the library](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/blob/master/uploadservice/src/main/java/net/gotev/uploadservice/UploadService.java#L77).

You may also raise a feature request at [android-upload-service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/issues).